# Linking my encryption class to the DB and HTML form

Tags: php, html, encryption

I'm going to jump in straight away.. I currently have the following code:

An Encryption Class:

```
class Encryption {
    var $skey = "cryptkey";

    public  function safe_b64encode($string) {
        $data = base64_encode($string);
        $data = str_replace(array('+','/','='),array('-','_',''),$data);
        return $data;
    }

    public function safe_b64decode($string) {
        $data = str_replace(array('-','_'),array('+','/'),$string);
        $mod4 = strlen($data) % 4;
        if ($mod4) {
            $data .= substr('====', $mod4);
        }
        return base64_decode($data);
    }

    public  function encode($value){ 
        if(!$value){return false;}
        $text = $value;
        $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
        $crypttext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $this->skey, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
        return trim($this->safe_b64encode($crypttext)); 
    }

    public function decode($value){
        if(!$value){return false;}
        $crypttext = $this->safe_b64decode($value); 
        $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
        $decrypttext = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $this->skey, $crypttext, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
        return trim($decrypttext);
    }
}
```

And this is the code used to utilise the class:

```
    $str = "password";

$converter = new Encryption;
$encoded = $converter->encode($str );
$decoded = $converter->decode($encoded);    

echo "$encoded<p>$decoded";
```

This is the HTML Form I'd like to run the encryption class on:

```
<form action="#" method="post">                                    
                  <div class="login-fields">

                    <div class="field">
                      <label for="website_name">Website Name</label>
                      <input type="text" id="webname" name="webname" value="" placeholder="Website Name" class="login website-field"/>
                    </div> <!-- /website name -->

                    <div class="field">
                      <label for="username">Username</label>
                      <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="" placeholder="Username" class="login username-field" />
                    </div> <!-- /field -->

                    <div class="field">
                      <label for="password">Password:</label>
                      <input type="password" id="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password" class="login password-field"/>
                    </div> <!-- /password -->

                    <div class="field">
                      <label for="cryptkey">Encryption Key:</label>
                      <input type="text" id="cryptkey" name="cryptkey" value="" placeholder="Encryption Key" class="login crypt-field"/>
                    </div> <!-- /password -->

                  </div> <!-- /login-fields -->

                  <div id="saveBtn">                 
                    <button class="button btn btn-index btn-large">Save</button>
                  </div> <!-- .actions -->



                </form>
```

And so this is basically what I'm trying to do. The form will accept input from the user to save the following information. The password is the only thing that needs to be encrypted; and the stored entries need to be saved on a separate table for each user.

How do I implement what I just stated above? Whereby whatever is inserted into the password field is encrypted and saved onto a database that is specific to a user's account? If anything needs clarifying please do ask and I'll try my best!

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You need to have a file that processes said form where you can access `$_POST['password']` - sanitize it and then encrypt and insert.

Comment: This is NOT a secure way to store passwords - they should be hashed not encrypted

Comment: @dbh could you please be so nice as to walk me through that process??

Comment: @user574632 I KNOW that, I need to store passwords I can retrieve later so hashing is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

As stated previously, you should hash instead of encrypt.

Now your form can have an action - lets say for example its called `process.php`.

Now on **`process.php`** you have to check that your data has been sent through.
That is easily done with:

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST)) {

}

?>
```

Now the next step is to sanitize, which I will leave up to you as many people have different methods of doing so.
The most important to do is to escape the strings for database insertion which is best practised with [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Now each of your inputs have a set name, for this example we will use the `password` input.
You'd access said input:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST)){
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    // Presuming you have sanitized your input, here is where you encrypt/hash your password
    $password = encrypt($password);

    // somewhere down here you'd be inserting said input into the database.
    // now you need to go and read about PDO (linked above) and execute an INSERT query.
}
?>
```

Comment: It says "encrypt" is undefined however it was obviously defined in the public function above it as encode. Neither are working. :(

Comment: @BeshoiMaher - This was merely an example not meant for copy - pasting. The **`encrypt`** will need to be your encryption class method exactly how you stated it above in your question.